# Border-radius "none-bug" in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

How to fix `border-radius` behavior in Chrome?

```css
table {
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
td {
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding:10px;
  background:lightgreen;
}
.tl {
  border-radius: 15px 0 0 0;
}
.tr {
  border-radius: 0 15px 0 0;
}
.br {
  border-radius: 0 0 15px 0;
}
.bl {
  border-radius: 0 0 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="tl">name1</td>
    <td class="tr">value1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="bl">name2</td>
    <td class="br">value2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In IE it works well.

Comment: it's not a bug :) it's working fine on Chrome and also Firefox BUT it's a bug in IE ... when using border collpase the border no more belong to td element and they collapse with table border .. and it's clearly defined in the spefication that it won't be considered : https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#border-radius-tables ... so you are not having an issue, it's like that

Comment: @TemaniAfif so I prefer this IE bug and not agree with specification: it is big inconvenience for making layout.

Comment: well it's up to you to agree or not, but as i said in my comment the importante part is that you need to understand that it's not a bug of chrome and it's normal behavior ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kind of solution, but I don't like this way

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border:.5px solid #000;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
td {
  border:.5px solid #000;
  padding:10px;
  background:lightgreen;
}
.tl {
  border-radius: 15px 0 0 0;
}
.tr {
  border-radius: 0 15px 0 0;
}
.br {
  border-radius: 0 0 15px 0;
}
.bl {
  border-radius: 0 0 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="tl">name1</td>
    <td class="tr">value1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="bl">name2</td>
    <td class="br">value2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

another one, a bit better

```css
table { 
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}
td {
  padding: 10px; 
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  background: lightgreen;
}
td:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.tl {
  border-radius: 15px 0 0 0;
}
.tr {
  border-radius: 0 15px 0 0;
}
.br {
  border-radius: 0 0 15px 0;
}
.bl {
  border-radius: 0 0 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="tl">name1</td>
    <td class="tr">value1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="bl">name2</td>
    <td class="br">value2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```